# Incompatible indexer with DataFrame while updating based on condition

Tags: python-3.x

```
data.loc[(data['Equipment ID']=='-')&(data['Ticket Title'].str.contains(r'uhn[0-9]', regex=True)),'Equipment ID'] = data[(data['Equipment ID']=='-')&(data['Ticket Title'].str.contains(r'uhn[0-9]', regex=True))]['Ticket Title'].str.extract(r'(uhn\w+)')
```

The syntax looks good but i get this error

-> 1268         raise ValueError("Incompatible indexer with DataFrame")
1269
1270     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: Tuple):

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
mask = (data['Equipment ID']=='-')&(data['Ticket Title'].str.contains(r'uhn[0-9]', regex=True))

data.loc[mask, 'Equipment ID'] = data.loc[mask, 'Ticket Title'].str.extract(r'(uhn\w+)')
```

Comment: Not sure if it is something with my data. still does not allow me to make the update. A pretty neat way to reduce complexity. thank you

Answer (score 0):

had to use `.values.reshape(-1,)`

final code

```
data.loc[(data['Equipment ID']=='-')&(data['Ticket Title'].str.contains(r'uhn[0-9]', regex=True)),'Equipment ID'] = data[(data['Equipment ID']=='-')&(data['Ticket Title'].str.contains(r'uhn[0-9]', regex=True))]['Ticket Title'].str.extract(r'(uhn\w+)').values.reshape(-1,)
```

still not sure why I got the error